# ERROR: gcloud.dns.managed-zone.create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I use : google cloud VM that works very well with gcloud command line.
I followed started with Google Cloud DNS .
- Install the Cloud SDK
- Authenticate on the command-line 
- create a project 
- set api dns
- verify domain ownership .
but when I execute:

```
 gcloud managed dns - area create --dns_name = " mydomaine.com . " --description = " A test zone" mydomainezonename
Creating {' dNSName ' : ' name' ' mydomaine.com . ' ' Examplezone '
'description' : ' mydomaine test area '} in PROJECT

Do you want to continue (Y / n) ? Y

ERROR: ( gcloud.dns.managed - zone.create ) ResponseError : status = 400 = Bad Request code , reason (s) = invalid
message = Invalid value for project: PROJECT
```

I search on the web but I find no reason on my problem .

Comment: Can you re-run with the --project=Project_ID flag appended, where Project_ID is the Project ID, not the name? Do you see the same response?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply I used the project name and not the ID .